# OpenMP on Tile Based Processors

Tags: multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp, multicore

I am curious to find out about the implications of using OpenMP on a many-core processor with a high amount of cores, specifically on the MAESTRO board. The MAESTRO board has 49 processors arranged in a two-dimensional array in a 7x7 configuration. Each core has its own L1 and L2 cache. A layout of the board can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qbRM.png

I have been trying to run some matrix multiplication code that uses OpenMP and the nature of the speedup is not how I expected. Running this code on a regular computer, say my laptop, I notice that as I increase the amount of threads to use I get a decrease in execution time. Running the OpenMP code results in a big performance increase as I would expect.

However, running this same code on the MAESTRO does not yield this same result. Using OpenMP seems to make it run slower and I was only able to get an increase in performance after messing with the cache coherence settings of the arrays being used and experimenting with different scheduling techniques that OpenMP provides. Even then, the speedup was minimal. I could only increase the amount of threads up to a certain point before I saw a performance decrease, and if I made the arrays too large the OpenMP code runs slower than the serial code.

After looking online, I saw some papers discussing "Tile Aware Parallelization in OpenMP", saying that OpenMP is "tile oblivious" (http://www.capsl.udel.edu/pub/doc/papers/Gan-IWOMP2009.pdf). I'm not sure how relevant that is, but it was the only thing I could really fine that discusses using OpenMP on a tile-based processor with a high amount of cores.

So I guess my main questions are: How does the nature of an OpenMP program change when going from a normal desktop computer, to a high-performance many-core processor like the tile based MAESTRO? Is the performance of OpenMP on the MAESTRO something I can improve or is there a ceiling I will hit due to the type of processor? What could be the cause of a decrease of performance when trying to parallelize code using OpenMP on a processor such as the MAESTRO? Would it be more beneficial to focus on other ways of parallelizing code, such as using MPI?

The current code I have been running on the MAESTRO:

```
alloc_attr_t attrA = ALLOC_INIT;
alloc_attr_t attrB = ALLOC_INIT;
alloc_attr_t attrC = ALLOC_INIT;

alloc_set_home(&attrA, ALLOC_HOME_INCOHERENT);
alloc_set_home(&attrB, ALLOC_HOME_INCOHERENT);
alloc_set_home(&attrC, ALLOC_HOME_TASK);

INT32_TYPE *A=alloc_map(&attrA, sizeof(INT32_TYPE)*(size*size));
INT32_TYPE *B=alloc_map(&attrB, sizeof(INT32_TYPE)*(size*size));
INT64_TYPE *C=alloc_map(&attrC, sizeof(INT64_TYPE)*(size*size));



  for(i=0;i<(size*size);i++)
   {
        A[i]=rand();
        B[i]=rand();
        C[i]=0;

}



 TIME_GET(&start);

    //parallelize with OpenMP

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(threads) private(i,j,k) schedule(dynamic)
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<size;k++)
            {

                C[i*size+j]+=A[i*size+k]*B[k*size+j];

            }
        }
    }


    TIME_GET(&end);
```

Note: This configuration has yielded the best performance from what I have tested. I have tried different cache coherence settings, different scheduling techniques, different chunk sizes, and collapsing the loop to different levels.

Comment: Thread affinity is a crucial topic when executing in these systems. The OS may want to move threads fro one core to another and that may be source of many penalties (e.g. cache bot efficiently reused). Thread affinity allows the user specify where threads can run. Check if you have this feature in your runtime.

Comment: In addition to @Harald 's comment, I'd say that the code you chosen is memory bandwidth bound unless you manage to fit the data in cache, possibly via loop-tiling. In this sort of hardware with limited / convoluted access to memory, this cache blocking technique (along with thread affinity) becomes even more crucial to achieve performance. For the sake of playing with the hardware, you should start with a less cache-sensitive algorithm.